# Changing URL for site collection

Tags: site-collection, url, team-sites

We have a SharePoint 2010 intranet site, what is the easiest way to change URL for a site collection(team site)?we do not want to create another SC, we just want to change the URL, we are looking for some other solution like:

- Reverse proxy URL construct
- AAM or host header site collection

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure about the reverse proxy, but their is a trusted way which i adopt all the time for path based site collections.

- take the backup of current site collection
- restore the site collection with new URL.
- once site restored on new url, test it and after that delete the old site collection.

But if this is only site collection in the Web app then you can change the AAM settings.

If this is HNSC collection then you can add another url to it.

Comment: since there are some other SC under this Web App, can we create the  AAM only for one sc.

Comment: No, aam settings are Web app level.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the URL for the entire web requires you to:
- Create a new DNS entry for the new domain name
- Create an AAM (Alternate Access Mapping) in Central Admin for the new domain name
- If IIS isn't automatically updated (I cannot recall this), create a new entry in IIS for the new host header (domain name) and point it to the appropriate directory for the site collection

If you only require the site collection's url to change, and are utilizing the existing domain name (ex: www.domain.com/subweb) you can create a managed path for the Web, and attach the site collection to that.

Comment: Thanks, How can I attache the site collection to managed path? it is gonna change the SC's URL?

Comment: You will need to backup, delete, then restore the site collection via powershell if you want to modify an existing site collection.
Create your managed path first, then perform the following steps detailed here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/501421/Change-Site-Collection-URL-in-SharePoint